# How to display grandparent when child is given

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, hierarchy

How to display grandparent when 'childItemNo' is given.

Below is my model: Any record (ItemNo) can become a grandparent, parent or child.

```
public partial class item
{      
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }         
    public string ParentItemNo { get; set; }     
}
```

Below query returns parent when childItemNo is given: Would like to display grandparent as well.

```
  var result =  DbContext.ItemTables.Where(p => p.ItemNo== childItemNo).Select(p => p.ParentItemNo).ToListAsync();
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you have navigation properties, this is trivial: `Select(c => c.Parent.ParentItemNo)`, without them, slightly more dirty: `Select(c => DbContext.ItemTables.First(p => p.ItemNo == c.ParentItemNo).ParentItemNo)`. Put nav props; it's how EF makes life easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have navigation properties, this is trivial:

```
Select(c => c.Parent.ParentItemNo)
```

Without them, you could go slightly more dirty:

```
Select(c => DbContext.ItemTables.First(p => p.ItemNo == c.ParentItemNo).ParentItemNo)
```

Or use a join

```
(from ch in db.ItemTables
join pa in db.ItemTables
on ch.ParentItemNo equals pa.ItemNo
where ch.ItemNo == childItemNo
select pa.ParentItemNo).First()
```

Or in method syntax:

```
db.ItemTables.Where(ch => ch.ItemNo == childItemNo).Join(
  db.ItemTables,
  l => l.ParentItemNo, //left is the child
  r => r.ItemNo,       //right is the parent
  (l, r) => r.ParentItemNo  //want the parent's parent
).First();
```